# Generate random data before active_admin_import

Tags: ruby-on-rails, import, activeadmin

I want to use active_admin_import to import data from a csv.

One of the columns to be added for each entry into the model is a random generated string. In the csv I created a header for it but leave it blank in every row.

How do I generate a random string for each of them before they get inserted into the table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one of the way of doing this

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

...
  before_validate do 
   self.unique_column = SecureRandom.hex(8) # or other way for generating unique string
  end
...
end
```

and resource

```
  ActiveAdmin.register MyModel do
        active_admin_import  validate: true
  end
```